# How to preserve color when extracting thumbnail from videos with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, color-space

I'm using FFMPEG to extract thumbnails from arbitrary user-submitted videos to jpg and the outputs are noticeably darker than the input video.

Here is an image captured of a MP4 input (SMPTE Color Bars) using Mac OS's built in screen capture utility (which seems to have a reasonably accurate color representation.  Red value on this image is R: 191, G: 0, B: 1.
[image: brighter image of SMPTE color bars]

Here is the same image captured using the FFMPEG script below.  Red value on this image is R: 176, G: 0, B: 2.
[image: diminished brightness image of SMPTE color bars]

Here is the ffmpeg options I'm using to extract these images:

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.mp4 \
    -vframes 1 \
    -filter:v scale=600:-1 \
    -qscale:v 90 \
    -f singlejpeg \
    thumb.jpg
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

(Note that while there are *related* topics on Stack Overflow, all of them are specific to known input video types.  I'm looking for a solution that will work across arbitrary inputs.)

Comment: What is the video codec of the MP4 video file? What is the pixel format of the input video?

Comment: I am getting an error `Requested output format 'singlejpeg' is not a suitable output format`. The 'singlejpeg' format is obsolete. What is the version of FFmpeg? Can you test it with version: 5.1.2 ?

Comment: Sure.  I'll attempt your answer with the latest FFMPEG (5.1.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in FFmpeg that also applies the latest stable current release (version 5.1.2).
I was able to reproduce the issue using Windows 10, so the bug is not specific to MacOS.

[Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199238/jpeg-colors-worse-than-png-when-extracting-frames-with-ffmpeg) from 2016, describing the same issue].

---

The solution I found is appending `out_color_matrix=bt601:out_range=pc` to the scale filter:

`ffmpeg -y -i color_bars.mp4 -vframes 1 -filter:v scale=600:-1:out_color_matrix=bt601:out_range=pc -qscale:v 0 thumb.jpg`

- `out_color_matrix=bt601` - applies BT.601 as output color space.
- `out_range=pc` - applies full range of YUV (full range is [0, 255], and in "TV range" / "limited range", the range of Y is [16, 235]).

---

According [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion) JPEG color conversion applies BT.601 "full range" YUV format, and the arguments `out_color_matrix=bt601:out_range=pc` were selected accordingly.

Adding `out_color_matrix=bt601:out_range=pc`, forces FFmpeg to apply color format conversion that matches JPEG standard.

The bug is that by default FFmpeg doesn't apply color format conversion, and keeps the original color format, which is presumably "limited range" [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.709_conversion).
Keeping the original color format (without conversion) results a "color shift".

---

Reproducing the issue:

- Download the PNG image from the question and rename the file to `color_bars.png`.
- Create an MP4 video from the PNG image:
  `ffmpeg -y -i color_bars.png -loop 100 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -crf 10 -pix_fmt yuv444p -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0:colour_primaries=1:transfer_characteristics=1:matrix_coefficients=1 color_bars.mp4`
  The conversion applies BT.709 "limited range" format.
  The bitstream filter marks the H.264 video stream as BT.709 "limited range" format.
- Convert single frame to JPEG without color conversion:
  `ffmpeg -y -i color_bars.mp4 -vframes 1 -filter:v scale=600:-1 -qscale:v 90 thumb.jpg`
- Convert single frame to JPEG with color conversion:
  `ffmpeg -y -i color_bars.mp4 -vframes 1 -filter:v scale=600:-1:out_color_matrix=bt601:out_range=pc -qscale:v 0 thumb2.jpg`

---

Results:
`thumb.jpg` - without color conversion:
[image]
The RGB values of the red pixels are [176, 0, 2].

`thumb2.jpg` - with color conversion:
[image]
The RGB values of the red pixels are [190, 0, 0] (there is an acceptable rounding error).

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.

Will this approach work across video codecs (H264 / H265) within .mp4 containers?

Comment: Great... I wonder why there is so little information about that kind of color shift, converting video to sequence of JPEG images is a common task.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem for the great answer. I tried replicating the solution but was unable to do so. Extracting the "thumb.jpeg"  without color conversion (exactly as shown above) results in an image with artifacts: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a82Jm2ALJyFwCsXEeZ1dX-uUubV_WGA0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @eeg Have you tried the exact same stages as in my answer, and got different results? It could be due to different version of FFmpeg. I think I used FFmpeg version 5.1. Make sure you repeat the exact same steps.